# Validate parameters passed into the URLFOR function

Tags: visualforce, urlfor

What is the best way to check if parameters passed into a URLFOR function are valid?

I am trying to pass in a target and id without any inputs or an override param.

**Example:**

URLFOR(param1,param2)

I'm trying to check for Null and blank values.

```
    {!IF(Param1 != NULL && Param2 != NULL),
                                    '',
                                    URLFOR(BLANKVALUE(Param1),BLANKVALUE(Param2,''))
                                    )}
```

Comment: Are param1 and param2 values from the controller (standard or custom)?. Did you look at the ISBLANK(..) function?